# Get all videos uploaded by my account with a specific tag Vimeo API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, vimeo-api

I need to get all the videos uploaded by me that contains a specific tag, i'm currently using the Node.js SDK with the current method:

```
vimeo.request({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/me/videos'
  }, function (error, body, status_code, headers) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    console.log(body)
})
```

And it returns all the videos uploaded on my account succesfully,
but i don't know how to get all my videos with the tag 'reel', for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to specify a tag and get all videos on an account with that tag. You can only [get all public videos on Vimeo with a specified tag](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos_with_tag).

You can make a request to /me/videos and use the `fields` parameter to return only the tag metadata, and then iterate through the list to get only the tags you require.

That request might look something like this:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?fields=uri,tags' 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but now there is a way to filter or query

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?filter_tag=yourtag' 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

or

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?query=yourtag&query_fields=tags' 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

Comment: not working for me, tried both ways, first one returns nothings, second returns everything